# Change back to ViewController after certain time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create an app that has a navigation bar at the bottom of the first view controller. When the user presses next they are taken to the second view controller in the storyboard. I would like to know if it is possible to make the program automatically take the user back to the first view controller after 10 seconds? I am very new to xcode so any help implementing this in a simple fashion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

just create a function and call that after time delay and push in that

in second viecontroller

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
  }



-(void)yourMethod
{
  //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a complete noob in xcode and objective-c so i apologize for my lack of knowledge. Do I want to place this method in the file for my first view controller or second?

Comment: in second viewcontroller perform selector in viewdidload and paste method in same controller

Comment: So I have added this piece of code to the viewdidload method

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil      afterDelay:10.0];

Comment: and also added the other method. Is there something else that must be done to make it revert back to the first view controller?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages however it is not reverting me back to the first controller

Comment: first check yourMethod is called or not and let me know how u push to second viewcontroller

Comment: sorry I feel as if Im hopeless, all I have done is place a button in first view controller and created a modal to second view controller. All I would like is for it to revert back to first view controller 10 seconds after the button is pushed. I have added no code but the method you gave me

Comment: @user3492592 Did you say you've done a 'modal' segue? because in that case you're not using a navigation controller and you should be  sending the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method to the presenting view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to viewDidLoad in your second view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
[self performSelector:@selector(viewWillDisappear:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
//I have given 2 seconds. you can change as your wish
}
```

Add this method too below.

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope it works..